# Best way to ask a user to input a date?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

How can I ask my user to input a date in my Blackberry application?

What controls does the RIM offer me to show my users something familiar and easy to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [DateField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/DateField.html) control.  Also - new to the 5.0 API is a [DateTimePicker](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/picker/DateTimePicker.html) control which is an improved version of the control.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working on a Blackberry Web content, you might want to use HTML5 for getting dates,

```
<div>
<b>Date Input:</b> <br/>
Dates between 2010 - 2018: <input type="date" id="txtDate"  min="2010-01-01" max="2018-12-31" value=""/>
</div>
```